# Remove characters from list which contains numeric and characters without NA coercion message

Tags: r

I've got a list which contains numbers and text items. I want to remove the text items and keep the numeric items. I don't mind using a few lines of code, So I can do the below with with x, then remove the NAs using another line.  **BUT** I want to avoid the NAs coercion warning message.

```
x <- c(1,"_2",3 , 6 , "1_" , "a")
as.numeric(x)
[1]  1 NA  3  6 NA NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `grep` from base R to get values that only contain digits ie `^\\d+$` or use `\\D` to get those that contain non-digits and invert the regex to match only digits:

```
as.numeric(grep("\\D", x, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE))
[1] 1 3 6

as.numeric(grep("^\\d+$", x, value = TRUE))
[1] 1 3 6
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `suppressWarnings` to muffle the warnings

```
suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))
[1]  1 NA  3  6 NA NA
```

---

Or with `str_subset`

```
library(tidyr)
as.numeric(str_subset(x, "^\\d+$"))
[1] 1 3 6
```