# How can I find a character of a numeric value in a column of character values that are constructed of numbers and letters?

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, character, numeric

Let's say I have a dataframe as follows (but much bigger)

```
df = data.frame(x = c('1E','2E',3,4,5) )
```

I wish to be able to find the rows numbers that have the characters 3,4 and 5 that do not have letters. Appreciate the help.

Comment: It's very unclear. If you just want 3, 4, and 5, `subset(df, x %in% 3:5)` is ok, no need of any regex.

Comment: Maybe `grep("[^0-9]", df$x, invert=TRUE)`

Comment: Exactly simiar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75488957/remove-characters-from-list-which-contains-numeric-and-characters-without-na-coe/75488981#75488981

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grepl()` and look for `3`, `4`, or `5` and only rows that start `^` and end `$` with those numbers:

```r
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(x = c('1E','2E',3,4,5) )

df %>% filter(grepl(paste0("^(",paste(3:5, collapse = "|"), ")$"), x))
#>   x
#> 1 3
#> 2 4
#> 3 5
```

If you have more than one column you can use `if_any` to search all character columns for those strings:

```r
df %>% filter(if_any(where(is.character),
                     ~ grepl(paste0("^(",paste(3:5, collapse = "|"), ")$"), .x)))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>